# WCF Rest XML EndPoint.(HTTPPOST). Deserialise an external object

Tags: c#, xml, wcf

I have a Service contract which is supposed to accept a widget as an input parameter.
The widget spec was given to me by a third party which will be using the contract.
I made the appropriate data contracts and can use a unit test (which is using the WCF as a service reference) to serialize a widget and do the HTTP POST.

It is a bare bones XML serialization that is embedded in the body of the HTTPPOST. It is not a well formed xml document.
e.g.

```
 StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        XmlTextWriter xtw = new XmlTextWriter(sw);
        xtw.WriteStartElement("Widget");
        xtw.WriteElementString("DateTime", widget.DateTime);
        xtw.WriteStartElement("Status");
        foreach (MyServRef.Status status in widget.Status)
        {
            xtw.WriteStartElement("Status");
            xtw.WriteElementString("Bay", status.Bay.ToString());
            xtw.WriteElementString("CurrentState", status.CurrentState.ToString());
            xtw.WriteElementString("Sector", status.Sector.ToString());
            xtw.WriteElementString("SpaceId", status.SpaceId.ToString());
            xtw.WriteElementString("StatusId", status.StatusId.ToString());
            xtw.WriteElementString("TransitionDateTime", status.TransitionDateTime);
            xtw.WriteEndElement();
        }
        xtw.WriteEndElement();
        xtw.WriteElementString("UniqueId", message.UniqueId.ToString());
        xtw.WriteEndElement();
        xtw.Close();

        string xml = sw.ToString();
```

When the third party tries to use the contract there is an Error 400. They are using a fully formatted xml doc which has namespace declarations in it.
e.g.

```
    <Widget xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    UniqueId="8cf4df0f-e765-4afc-b6fa-cd90b07b67b2"
    DateTime="2015-08-02T01:00:29.2213364Z" xmlns="http://www.thesite.com/">
      <Status>
        <SpaceId>00010003</SpaceId>
        <StatusId>1658038</StatusId>     
      </Status>
    </Widget>
```

The contract is:

```
 [OperationContract]//Don't decorate XML REST Contracts use   web.config       
    Response MyContract(Widget widget);
```

The Data Contract is;

```
[DataContract(Namespace = "")]
public class Widget
{


    private string _uniqueIdField;

    private string _dateTimeField;



    [DataMember]

    public Status[] Status
    {
        get;
        set;

    }

    [DataMember]
    public string UniqueId
    {
        get { return _uniqueIdField; }
        set { _uniqueIdField = value; }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public string DateTime
    {
        get { return _dateTimeField; }
        set { _dateTimeField = value; }
    }
}
```

I have tried many options including an alternate contract that takes a string parameter and then used a DataContractSerializer to deserialize the widget.

Essentially I haven't a clue  how to do this and am floundering around looking for the correct way. 
Would appreciate anything that can help me solve this.
thanks

Comment: I think there is an issue in your request XML. XML start with "widget" tag but end with "message" tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can make a .net winform app and reference your service does that work? If that works you should be able to wireshark the requests to see what the difference is between your winform app and the third party's request.

Comment: I am so thoroughly confused the question is relevant to the problem. Lets take this as the answer until I can frame a new question.